# Optimized code for Insert and Update in one method with LINQ?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a form with Textboxes and other controls containing object properties. Both inserting and updating use this form; the variable `updatingId` (unique ID of row) is only assigned a value when updating.

The 'Save' button would have something like this:

```
    Using db As New DBDataContext
        Dim wrestlerEntity As New wrestler
        With wrestlerEntity
            .alias_1 = TextBox1.Text
            .alias_2 = TextBox2.Text
            .stage_name = TextBox3.Text 'etc...
        End With

        'Insert/update
        If updatingId Is Nothing Then
            'Insert
            db.wrestlers.InsertOnSubmit(wrestlerEntity)
        Else
            'Update
            Dim updatingRow = (From a In db.wrestlers
                               Where a.ID = updatingId
                               Select a).Single

            'With updatingRow
            '    .alias_1 = TextBox1.Text
            '    .alias_2 = TextBox2.Text
            '    .stage_name = TextBox3.Text
            'End With
        End If

        'Execute
        db.SubmitChanges()
    End Using
```

As you can see, the code on the Update block (commented out) is basically copy-pasted from the initialization of `wrestlerEntity` at the top. Any more simpler way of achieving this? I tried a guess with:

```
updatingRow = wrestlerEntity
```

...to no avail.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic approach is to make a `Function` (or rather, `Sub`) to perform the repetitive statements:

```
  Private Sub PerformAct(entity As wrestler)
    With entity
        .alias_1 = TextBox1.Text
        .alias_2 = TextBox2.Text
        .stage_name = TextBox3.Text 'etc...
    End With
  End Sub
```

Thus you can simplify your main block as follow:

```
Using db As New DBDataContext
    Dim wrestlerEntity As New wrestler
    PerformAct(wrestlerEntity)

    'Insert/update
    If updatingId Is Nothing Then
        'Insert
        db.wrestlers.InsertOnSubmit(wrestlerEntity)
    Else
        'Update
        Dim updatingRow = (From a In db.wrestlers
                           Where a.ID = updatingId
                           Select a).Single
        PerformAct(updatingRow)
    End If

    'Execute
    db.SubmitChanges()
End Using
```

And you can reuse the `PerformAct` as many times as you want

Comment: Cool! So considering I have other forms for managers, coaches and others, the way to go is to create their own version of `PerformAct`?

Comment: @AwonDanag yes, and if among the `PerformAct`s of the other forms you have something repetitive in common, you could further create `Sub` or `Function` for those similar repetitive blocks too - ad inifinitum. The point is to reduce to duplicate, use `Function` or `Sub`